# Unique decomposition of invertible matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

> Show that if matrix $A \in \mbox{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $A$ has decomposition $A=LR$, where $L$ is a normed triangular matrix $(a_{ii}=1$, for all $i$.) and $R$ is an invertible upper triangular matrix then the decomposition is unique.

---

I was trying to prove this and thought about using the fact that if a matrix has an inverse it is unique so my understanding was if $A=LR \implies A^{-1}=(LR)^{-1}=R^{-1}L^{-1}$ has to be unique but I'm not sure if this statement implies that the original decomposition is unique. Is there a simpler way to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that $L$ is lower triangular. Suppose $A$ has two such decompositions $A = L_1R_1 = L_2R_2$. Then $L_{2}^{-1}L_1 = R_2R_{1}^{-1}$. It is easy to check that the LHS is lower triangular and has $1$ on the diagonal and that the RHS is upper triangular. It follows that both sides are the identity matrix.

Comment: The first assumption is crucial, but I was also going to assume it because what else could $L$ be an abbreviation of?

Comment: Ehm, on closer inspection, given the abbreviation $R$ for the upper triangular one, $L$ could also be an abbreviation for 'left'. But it seems the statement is false if $L$ is allowed to be uppertriangular so I guess this answer is the correct one.